# Html/Css Imgs not displaying correctly in IE and resizing (LEFT instead of RIGHT)

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I tried researching solutions to this on Stack but I couldn't find anything that helped me. You can check out my website at jmltechnologie.com   I'm a hardware person and i'm very amateur at Html/css, so please give me any tips you see :D

My problem atm is the Images. I can't resize them with @media for mobile and when I open my website on an older version of IE (Which I suspect many users still use, especially the one that might check my website) they show on the left instead of the right... Frustrating.

I'm asking for basic tips and tricks to poisition my images correctly and to be able to resize them on mobile. Here's an example of my code and check my website to better understand the issue. Tyvm

```css
.test123 table {
  width: 90%;
  float: center;
  margin: 125px auto 10px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 55px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}

.test123 td {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.test123 img {
  margin-top: 6%;
  margin-left: 22%;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="test123">
  <h1 id="Personnalisez-votre-ordinateur">Assemblage</h1>
  <h2>Terminé la lenteur, les annonces publicitaires, la perte de données et l’odeur de brulé;<br> Augmentez votre productivé grâce à nos PC personnalisés</h2>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">


        <img src="https://jmltechnologie.com/assemblage.png" width="220" height="150" alt="Assemblage d'ordinateur">
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111">Nos ordinateurs sur mesure ne contiennent aucun logiciel préinstallé qui pourraient nuire au rendement de votre ordinateur.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111">Bénéficier de nos <strong>conseils gratuits</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111">Vos avez déjà vos pièces, mais vous éprouvez des difficultés?<br> <strong>Nous pouvons vous aider.</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111">Nous nous occupons de <strong>tout</strong>: Choix des pièces, l'assemblage et l'installation à domicile.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111">Vous obtenez toujours plus de performance à meilleur prix, lorsque vous décidez d'assembler votre ordinateur.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color: #111111"><strong>Peu importe votre budget</strong>, nous serons en mesure de vous assembler un ordinateur performant.</td>
        </tr>





  </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<td>` above your image you have:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
```

Change it to:

```
<td style="text-align:left">
```

Comment: Ty, Will try it live.

Comment: Ty, I tried it but all it did is move my img to the left which is not what I'm looking for. I like how my website displays on Full screen on Chrome and Firefox but I must learn how to proper code the position of my images so resize when the screen is minimized. Just like when you open it on mobile. So far I only have the first img ( the graph) which I can't position correctly but I am suspecting  the way that I coded the table and the Img. I'm looking for any tips to display some text and an image beside it that will resize.